# Ajax says undefined property when returning json

Tags: jquery

I seem to be in a little bit of a pickle.

I cant get the ajax to return the value UserID, I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

Heres the PHP:

```
$array = array(
    "UserID" => $row['UserID']
    , "runDate" => $row['runDate']
    , "firstName" => $row['firstName']
    , "Time" => $row['Time']
    , "Time" => $row['Distance']
);   
echo  json_encode($array);
```

And the AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "searchbydateMySQLi.php",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: "date=" + $('input[name="date"]').val(),
    success: function(data){ 
        console.log(data.UserID[0]);
    },
});
```

Ive tried switching the datatype to HTML and it returns the whole string.

Comment: Where should I add that?

Comment: just do `data.UserId` without the `[0]` are you sure it's getting you `undefined` ?

Comment: now i'm getting nothing. WHat you wanna see, php or js?

Comment: Now its showing nothing at all

Comment: There is actually a syntax error after the closing `}` from the success function. Is this just a copy/paste error or does it exist in your JS?

Comment: yeh, dont laugh though http://www.myrunclub.co.uk/relayroute.html# . Go and click on the 6/01/2013

Comment: well it's json, and empty. hang on, I missed out the echo in my code then edited. do you have echo before json_encode?

Comment: yep echo json_encode($array);

Comment: Well there's a response. It's throwing mysqli errors.

Comment: Let me know if fixing the mysqli connection doesn't fix it

Comment: @popnoodles if i change the data type to HTML it brings back the string

Comment: `<p>run date: 2013-01-06</p><br><br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysqld.sock' (2) in <b>/homepages/42/d450493397/htdocs/searchbydateMySQLi.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
Failed to connect to MySQL: (2002) Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysqld.sock' (2)<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in <b>/homepages/42/d450493397/htdocs/searchbydateMySQLi.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
<br /><b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function fetch_array() on a...`

Comment: I had another echo before the echo of the jSON, stalling it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When echoing json you must set the content type because browsers don't recognise the string that PHP sends by default as `text/html` is json, which means your `data` variable is not as you expect. To be fair why should the browser work it out?

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($array);
die;
```

And it's a good idea to die/exit right afterwards

Comment: Look in your console. Is searchbydateMySQLi.php returning a 200 header?

Comment: Actually since you haven't shown any other code, what does `console.log(data)` show? For all we know there could be other text in there